# Customising data annotations in dynamic data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data, data-annotations

I have come across a scenerio that to customize DataAnnotations in Dynamic Data Web Application. This is the scenerio:

**[Display(Name="DispName")]**

**public string DName{get;set;}**

Instead of hardcoding Name="DispName" for Display DataAnnotation, I want to fetch some value from DataBase and fit int the Name attribute. like:

**[Display(Name=SomeValueFromDB)]**

**public string DName{get;set;}**

Is there any way to show the Name attribute of Display DataAnnotation from database instead of hardcoding its value?

Thanks in advance,

Sujith

Answer (score 12):

I found a solution. But this is applicable only if we build the application:

Create a custom class (Say: **CustomDisplayNameAttribute** ) which inherits **DisplayNameAttribute**. And call that class name as display attribute (here "**CustomDisplayName**") above the property name.

While setting DataAnnotation for Display attribute, omit that "Attribute" part from the class name. ie. the DataAnnotation for Display attribute will be **CustomDisplayName** (not CustomDisplayNameAttribute).

```
  public class DomainClass
{
    [CustomDisplayName("")]
    public object PropertyName{ get; set; }
}



public class CustomDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
    {
        public CustomDisplayNameAttribute(string value)
            : base(GetMessageFromResource(value))
        { }

        private static string GetMessageFromResource(string value)
        {
            return "Custom Display Name";
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps all....

Happy Coding....

Comment: this is very useful, now I can use multiple languages without much effort